# How to send headers via Axios to a Spring-Boot application?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, axios

I'm trying to make a webapplication with SpringBoot and Reactjs. I'm having trouble managing the JWT. By using Postman I can send my header 'jwt' and test my app and it works. But when I try via React using

```
axios.get('URL/logout', { headers: { jwt: localvariable } } )
          .then(response => {
                console.log('Response of logout', response);
                this.setState({isLogged: false});
                console.log('Status after logout', this.state);

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);

            });
```

i can't receive any header 'jwt' from the client side.
My code which handle the request from client is:

```
    @CrossOrigin("*")

    @RestController
    public class LoginController {

        @RequestMapping("/logout")
            public ResponseEntity<JsonResponseBody> logoutUser(@RequestHeader(value="jwt") String jwt,HttpServletRequest request){
                   System.out.println("My jwt is: "+jwt);
                   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                }
}
```

and I just receive:

```
{
"timestamp": 1526311750256,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException",
"message": "Missing request header 'jwt' for method parameter of type String",
"path": "/logout"
}
```

Please, any suggestion? Maybe the client needs authorizations to send headers? I'm stuck. Thank you

Comment: I dont think JWT is a HTTP header. You may have to change your approach here. What exactly are you trying to achieve with the JWT value ?

Comment: I'm settting "jwt" as custom header

Comment: i'm trying to build up a login/logout session

Comment: is there any logs here System.out.println("My jwt is: "+jwt); ?
you can also set @RequestHeader annotation param to required=false

Comment: I tried that too: I removed the RequestParam and I used request.getHeader("jwt") to get it, but nothing. Maybe do I need to set something like Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Expose-Headers" ?? I don't know

Answer (score 3):

I succeded. I had to create an axios istance and now it works. Thank you to everyone

```
let instance = axios.create();
instance.defaults.headers.common['jwt'] = this.state.jwt;
instance.get('URL/logout')
        .then(response => {
console.log('Response of logout', response);

});
```